# select highest pairs from complex table

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to make a new dataframe from a selection of rows in a complex table of pairwise comparisons. I want to select the rows such that the 2 highest values of each pairwise comparison is selected.

Below is an example dataset:

```
dataframe <- data.frame(X1 = c("OP2413iiia","OP2413iiib","OP2413iiic","OP2645ii_a","OP2645ii_b","OP2645ii_c","OP2645ii_d","OP2645ii_e","OP3088i__a","OP5043___a","OP5043___b","OP5044___a","OP5044___b","OP5044___c","OP5046___a","OP5046___b","OP5046___c","OP5046___d","OP5046___e","OP5047___a","OP5047___b","OP5048___b","OP5048___c","OP5048___d","OP5048___e","OP5048___f","OP5048___g","OP5048___h","OP5049___a","OP5049___b","OP5051DNAa","OP5051DNAb","OP5051DNAc","OP5052DNAa","OP5053DNAa"),
                        gr1 = c("2","2","2","3","3","3","3","3","3","4","4","4","3","4","2","3","3","3","4","2","4","3","3","3","4","2","4","2","3","3","3","4","2","4","2"),
                        X2 = c("OP2413iiib","OP2413iiic","OP5046___a","OP2645ii_a","OP2645ii_a","OP2645ii_a","OP2645ii_b","OP2645ii_b","OP5046___a","OP2645ii_b","OP2645ii_c","OP2645ii_c","OP2645ii_c","OP2645ii_c","OP5048___e","OP2645ii_d","OP5046___a","OP2645ii_d","OP2645ii_d","OP2645ii_d","OP2645ii_d","OP2645ii_e","OP5048___e","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_e","OP2645ii_e","OP3088i__a","OP3088i__a","OP3088i__a","OP3088i__a","OP3088i__a","OP3088i__a","OP3088i__a"),
                        gr2 = c("3","3","3","4","4","4","2","2","2","2","4","4","4","4","4","2","2","2","2","2","2","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","3","3","3","3","3","3","3"),
                        value = c("1.610613e+00","1.609732e+00","8.829263e-04","1.080257e+01","1.111006e+01","1.110978e+01","4.048302e+00","5.610458e+00","5.609584e+00","9.911490e+00","1.078518e+01","1.133728e+01","1.133686e+01","1.738092e+00","9.247411e+00","5.170646e+00","6.074909e+00","6.074287e+00","6.212711e+00","3.769029e+00","5.793390e+00","1.124045e+01","1.163326e+01","1.163293e+01","7.752766e-01","1.008434e+01","1.222854e+00","6.469443e+00","1.610828e+00","1.784774e+00","1.784235e+00","9.434803e+00","4.512563e+00","9.582847e+00","4.309312e+00"))

expected_output_dataframe <- rbind(dataframe[10,],dataframe[34,],dataframe[32,],dataframe[15,],dataframe[3,],dataframe[17,])
```

Many thanks in advance
Cheers

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output?

Comment: @tmfmnk The new line in the question will give the expected output from the dataframe above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method works using dplyr. I created an extra column, `gr_pair`, to identify the pairwise groups.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

dataframe %>% 
  filter(gr1 != gr2) %>% # This case is excluded from your expected output
  mutate(gr_pair = paste(pmin(gr1, gr2), pmax(gr1, gr2), sep = ",")) %>%
  group_by(gr_pair) %>% 
  top_n(2, value) # Keep the top two rows in each group, sorted by value
```